# How to use bbox in long/lat with google/bing/etc… using mapserver‏

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, postgis, mapserver, epsg

The bbox of OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature works in utm when the baselayer is 900913 ie. google/bing/etc) and in long/lat when the baselayer is 4326 (ie. my postgis layers served by mapserver), no matter what overlays them. This is what openlayers says.

So, how can I force bbox to be in long/lat when I use one of my layers over google for example? I do want the bbox being in long/lat rather than 900913 (ie. using baselayer projection). I've read many webs about this but with geoserver, some posts about mapserver say that both EPSG:900913 and EPSG:4326 must be set in METADATA, I changed that and also assigned "srs" and "projection" (with the appropriate expression) in my layers (and in protocols) but with no effect in bbox at all. What else could I try?

Any idea will be appreciated, thanks in advance,

Gery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem is necessary to use prototype with OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature and then use .transform with epsg4326 and epsg900913, a bit more info about here: [OpenLayers.Class with OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609174/openlayers-class-with-openlayers-control-getfeature)